# Tinymce multiple instances in same page

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4, tinymce-plugins

I am using tinymce multiple instances in same page. When I try to insert image, I can but it will be added always in last text area fields( I have same 10 textarea with different name and id).

Html

```
<div class="admin__field field field-options_options_fieldset3ad06b8f111bff0225b3ee56e2a93cc4_content_1  with-note">
    <label class="label admin__field-label" for="options_fieldset3ad06b8f111bff0225b3ee56e2a93cc4_content_1" data-ui-id="adminhtml-widget-form-field-wysiwygeditor-0-text-parameters-content-1-label"><span>Content 1</span></label>
    <div class="admin__field-control control">
        <textarea id="options_fieldset3ad06b8f111bff0225b3ee56e2a93cc4_content_13662927431522736609" name="parameters[content_1]" class="textarea admin__control-textarea wysiwyg-editor" rows="5" cols="15" data-ui-id="product-tabs-attributes-tab-fieldset-element-textarea-parameters[content_1]" aria-hidden="true"></textarea>
        <button id="id_5abf1b8e544f38a8ca21aa8815613abd" title="WYSIWYG Editor" type="button" class="action-default scalable action-wysiwyg hidden" onclick="basewidgetWysiwygEditor.open('http://cei-shop.local/admin/catalog/product/wysiwyg/key/0367c4936326c7be6bf0fda5c407d274c1f3e4a9922173f53b72e75411d13406/', 'options_fieldset3ad06b8f111bff0225b3ee56e2a93cc4_content_13662927431522736609')" data-ui-id="widget-button-0">
            <span>WYSIWYG Editor</span>
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="scalable action-show-hide" style="" id="toggleoptions_fieldset3ad06b8f111bff0225b3ee56e2a93cc4_content_13662927431522736609"><span><span><span>Show / Hide Editor</span></span></span></button>            
    </div>
</div>

<div class="admin__field field field-options_options_fieldset3ad06b8f111bff0225b3ee56e2a93cc4_content_2  with-note">
    <label class="label admin__field-label" for="options_fieldset3ad06b8f111bff0225b3ee56e2a93cc4_content_2" data-ui-id="adminhtml-widget-form-field-wysiwygeditor-1-text-parameters-content-2-label"><span>Content 2</span></label>
    <div class="admin__field-control control">
        <textarea id="options_fieldset3ad06b8f111bff0225b3ee56e2a93cc4_content_26925735391522736609" name="parameters[content_2]" class="textarea admin__control-textarea wysiwyg-editor" rows="5" cols="15" data-ui-id="product-tabs-attributes-tab-fieldset-element-textarea-parameters[content_2]" aria-hidden="true"></textarea>
        <button id="id_504c308d5e46c342e202e961e97b2904" title="WYSIWYG Editor" type="button" class="action-default scalable action-wysiwyg hidden" onclick="basewidgetWysiwygEditor.open('http://cei-shop.local/admin/catalog/product/wysiwyg/key/0367c4936326c7be6bf0fda5c407d274c1f3e4a9922173f53b72e75411d13406/', 'options_fieldset3ad06b8f111bff0225b3ee56e2a93cc4_content_26925735391522736609')" data-ui-id="widget-button-1">
            <span>WYSIWYG Editor</span>
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="scalable action-show-hide" style="" id="toggleoptions_fieldset3ad06b8f111bff0225b3ee56e2a93cc4_content_26925735391522736609"><span><span><span>Show / Hide Editor</span></span></span></button>            
    </div>
</div>
```

setup.js

define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'tinymce',
    'mage/adminhtml/wysiwyg/tiny_mce/html5-schema',
    'mage/translate',
    'prototype',
    'mage/adminhtml/events',
    'mage/adminhtml/browser'
], function(jQuery, _, tinyMCE, html5Schema) {

```
vesBaseTinyMceWysiwygSetup = Class.create();

vesBaseTinyMceWysiwygSetup.prototype = {
    mediaBrowserOpener: null,
    mediaBrowserTargetElementId: null,

    initialize: function(htmlId, config) {
        if (config.baseStaticUrl && config.baseStaticDefaultUrl) {
            tinyMCE.baseURL = tinyMCE.baseURL.replace(config.baseStaticUrl, config.baseStaticDefaultUrl);
        }

        this.id = htmlId;
        this.config = config;
        this.schema = config.schema || html5Schema;



        _.bindAll(this, 'beforeSetContent', 'saveContent', 'onChangeContent', 'openFileBrowser', 'updateTextArea');

        varienGlobalEvents.attachEventHandler('tinymceChange', this.onChangeContent);
        varienGlobalEvents.attachEventHandler('tinymceBeforeSetContent', this.beforeSetContent);
        varienGlobalEvents.attachEventHandler('tinymceSaveContent', this.saveContent);

        if (typeof tinyMceEditors == 'undefined') {
            tinyMceEditors = $H({});
        }

        tinyMceEditors.set(this.id, this);
    },

    setup: function(mode) {
        if (this.config.widget_plugin_src) {
            tinyMCE.PluginManager.load('magentowidget', this.config.widget_plugin_src);
        }

        if (this.config.plugins) {
            this.config.plugins.each(function(plugin) {
                tinyMCE.PluginManager.load(plugin.name, plugin.src);
            });
        }

        if (jQuery.isReady) {
            tinyMCE.dom.Event.domLoaded = true;
        }

        tinyMCE.init(this.getSettings(mode));
    },

    getSettings: function(mode) {
        var plugins = 'inlinepopups,safari,pagebreak,style,layer,table,advhr,advimage,emotions,iespell,media,searchreplace,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras',
            self = this;

        if (this.config.widget_plugin_src) {
            plugins = 'magentowidget,' + plugins;
        }

        var magentoPluginsOptions = $H({});
        var magentoPlugins = '';

        if (this.config.plugins) {
            this.config.plugins.each(function(plugin) {
                magentoPlugins = plugin.name + ',' + magentoPlugins;
                magentoPluginsOptions.set(plugin.name, plugin.options);
            });
            if (magentoPlugins) {
                plugins = '-' + magentoPlugins + plugins;
            }
        }

        var settings = {
            mode: (mode != undefined ? mode : 'none'),
            elements: this.id,
            theme: 'advanced',
            plugins: plugins,
            theme_advanced_buttons1: magentoPlugins + 'magentowidget,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect',
            theme_advanced_buttons2: 'cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,forecolor,backcolor',
            theme_advanced_buttons3: 'tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,iespell,media,advhr,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen',
            theme_advanced_buttons4: 'insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,pagebreak',
            theme_advanced_toolbar_location: 'top',
            theme_advanced_toolbar_align: 'left',
            theme_advanced_statusbar_location: 'bottom',
            theme_advanced_resizing: true,
            theme_advanced_resize_horizontal: false,
            convert_urls: false,
            relative_urls: false,
            content_css: this.config.content_css,
            custom_popup_css: this.config.popup_css,
            magentowidget_url: this.config.widget_window_url,
            magentoPluginsOptions: magentoPluginsOptions,
            doctype: '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">',
            setup: function(ed){
                ed.onInit.add(self.onEditorInit.bind(self));

                ed.onSubmit.add(function(ed, e) {
                    varienGlobalEvents.fireEvent('tinymceSubmit', e);
                });

                ed.onPaste.add(function(ed, e, o) {
                    varienGlobalEvents.fireEvent('tinymcePaste', o);
                });

                ed.onBeforeSetContent.add(function(ed, o) {
                    varienGlobalEvents.fireEvent('tinymceBeforeSetContent', o);
                });

                ed.onSetContent.add(function(ed, o) {
                    varienGlobalEvents.fireEvent('tinymceSetContent', o);
                });

                ed.onSaveContent.add(function(ed, o) {
                    varienGlobalEvents.fireEvent('tinymceSaveContent', o);
                });

                var onChange = function(ed, l) {
                    varienGlobalEvents.fireEvent('tinymceChange', l);
                };

                ed.onChange.add(onChange);
                ed.onKeyUp.add(onChange);

                ed.onExecCommand.add(function(ed, cmd, ui, val) {
                    varienGlobalEvents.fireEvent('tinymceExecCommand', cmd);
                });
            }
        };

        // Set the document base URL
        if (this.config.document_base_url) {
            settings.document_base_url = this.config.document_base_url;
        }

        if (this.config.files_browser_window_url) {
            settings.file_browser_callback = function(fieldName, url, objectType, w) {
                varienGlobalEvents.fireEvent("open_browser_callback", {
                    win: w,
                    type: objectType,
                    field: fieldName
                });
            };
        }

        if (this.config.width) {
            settings.width = this.config.width;
        }

        if (this.config.height) {
            settings.height = this.config.height;
        }

        if (this.config.settings) {
            Object.extend(settings, this.config.settings)
        }

        return settings;
    },
    applySchema: function (editor) {
        var schema      = editor.schema,
            schemaData  = this.schema,
            makeMap     = tinyMCE.makeMap;

        jQuery.extend(true, {
            nonEmpty: schema.getNonEmptyElements(),
            boolAttrs: schema.getBoolAttrs(),
            whiteSpace: schema.getWhiteSpaceElements(),
            shortEnded: schema.getShortEndedElements(),
            selfClosing: schema.getSelfClosingElements(),
            blockElements: schema.getBlockElements()
        }, {
            nonEmpty: makeMap(schemaData.nonEmpty),
            boolAttrs: makeMap(schemaData.boolAttrs),
            whiteSpace: makeMap(schemaData.whiteSpace),
            shortEnded: makeMap(schemaData.shortEnded),
            selfClosing: makeMap(schemaData.selfClosing),
            blockElements: makeMap(schemaData.blockElements)
        });
    },
    openFileBrowser: function(o) {
        //console.log(o.win.tinyMCE.activeEditor.editorId);
        var typeTitle,
            storeId = this.config.store_id !== null ? this.config.store_id : 0,
            frameDialog = jQuery(o.win.frameElement).parents('[role="dialog"]'),
            wUrl = this.config.files_browser_window_url +
            'target_element_id/' + this.id + '/' +
            'store/' + storeId + '/';

        this.mediaBrowserOpener = o.win;
        this.mediaBrowserTargetElementId = o.field;

        if (typeof(o.type) != 'undefined' && o.type != "") {
            typeTitle = 'image' == o.type ? this.translate('Insert Image...') : this.translate('Insert Media...');
            wUrl = wUrl + "type/" + o.type + "/";
        } else {
            typeTitle = this.translate('Insert File...');
        }
        frameDialog = jQuery('[role="dialog"]');
        frameDialog.hide();
        jQuery('#mceModalBlocker').hide();

        MediabrowserUtility.openDialog(wUrl, false, false, typeTitle, {
            closed: function() {
                jQuery(document).find('[role="dialog"]').show();
                jQuery('#mceModalBlocker').show();
            }
        });
    },

    translate: function(string) {
        return jQuery.mage.__ ? jQuery.mage.__(string) : string;
    },

    getMediaBrowserOpener: function() {
        return this.mediaBrowserOpener;
    },

    getMediaBrowserTargetElementId: function() {
        return this.mediaBrowserTargetElementId;
    },

    getToggleButton: function() {
        return $('toggle' + this.id);
    },

    getPluginButtons: function() {
        return $$('#buttons' + this.id + ' > button.plugin');
    },

    turnOn: function(mode) {
        this.closePopups();

        this.setup(mode);

        tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, this.id);

        this.getPluginButtons().each(function(e) {
            e.hide();
        });

        return this;
    },

    turnOff: function() {
        this.closePopups();

        tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveControl', false, this.id);

        this.getPluginButtons().each(function(e) {
            e.show();
        });

        return this;
    },

    closePopups: function() {
        if (typeof closeEditorPopup == 'function') {
            // close all popups to avoid problems with updating parent content area
            closeEditorPopup('widget_window' + this.id);
            closeEditorPopup('browser_window' + this.id);
        }
    },

    toggle: function() {
        if (!tinyMCE.get(this.id)) {
            this.turnOn();
            return true;
        } else {
            this.turnOff();
            return false;
        }
    },

    onEditorInit: function (editor) {
        this.applySchema(editor);
    },

    onFormValidation: function() {
        if (tinyMCE.get(this.id)) {
            $(this.id).value = tinyMCE.get(this.id).getContent();
        }
    },

    onChangeContent: function() {
        // Add "changed" to tab class if it exists
        if (tinyMCE.get(this.id)) {
            jQuery('#' + this.id).val(tinyMCE.get(this.id).getContent()).trigger('change');
        }
        if (this.config.tab_id) {
            var tab = $$('a[id$=' + this.config.tab_id + ']')[0];
            if ($(tab) != undefined && $(tab).hasClassName('tab-item-link')) {
                $(tab).addClassName('changed');
            }
        }
    },

    // retrieve directives URL with substituted directive value
    makeDirectiveUrl: function(directive) {
        return this.config.directives_url.replace('directive', 'directive/___directive/' + directive);
    },

    encodeDirectives: function(content) {
        // collect all HTML tags with attributes that contain directives
        return content.gsub(/<([a-z0-9\-\_]+.+?)([a-z0-9\-\_]+=".*?\{\{.+?\}\}.*?".+?)>/i, function(match) {
            var attributesString = match[2];
            // process tag attributes string
            attributesString = attributesString.gsub(/([a-z0-9\-\_]+)="(.*?)(\{\{.+?\}\})(.*?)"/i, function(m) {
                return m[1] + '="' + m[2] + this.makeDirectiveUrl(Base64.mageEncode(m[3])) + m[4] + '"';
            }.bind(this));

            return '<' + match[1] + attributesString + '>';

        }.bind(this));
    },

    encodeWidgets: function(content) {
        return content.gsub(/\{\{widget(.*?)\}\}/i, function(match) {
            var attributes = this.parseAttributesString(match[1]);
            if (attributes.type) {
                attributes.type = attributes.type.replace(/\\\\/g, "\\");
                var imageSrc = this.config.widget_placeholders[attributes.type];
                var imageHtml = '<img';
                imageHtml += ' id="' + Base64.idEncode(match[0]) + '"';
                imageHtml += ' src="' + imageSrc + '"';
                imageHtml += ' title="' + match[0].replace(/\{\{/g, '{').replace(/\}\}/g, '}').replace(/\"/g, '&quot;') + '"';
                imageHtml += '>';

                return imageHtml;
            }
        }.bind(this));
    },

    decodeDirectives: function(content) {
        // escape special chars in directives url to use it in regular expression
        var url = this.makeDirectiveUrl('%directive%').replace(/([$^.?*!+:=()\[\]{}|\\])/g, '\\$1');
        var reg = new RegExp(url.replace('%directive%', '([a-zA-Z0-9,_-]+)'));
        return content.gsub(reg, function(match) {
            return Base64.mageDecode(match[1]);
        }.bind(this));
    },

    decodeWidgets: function(content) {
        return content.gsub(/<img([^>]+id=\"[^>]+)>/i, function(match) {
            var attributes = this.parseAttributesString(match[1]);
            if (attributes.id) {
                var widgetCode = Base64.idDecode(attributes.id);
                if (widgetCode.indexOf('{{widget') != -1) {
                    return widgetCode;
                }
                return match[0];
            }
            return match[0];
        }.bind(this));
    },

    parseAttributesString: function(attributes) {
        var result = {};
        attributes.gsub(/(\w+)(?:\s*=\s*(?:(?:"((?:\\.|[^"])*)")|(?:'((?:\\.|[^'])*)')|([^>\s]+)))?/, function(match) {
            result[match[1]] = match[2];
        });
        return result;
    },

     updateTextArea: function () {
        var editor = tinyMCE.get(this.id),
            content;

        if (!editor) {
            return;
        }

        content = editor.getContent();
        content = this.decodeContent(content);

        jQuery('#' + this.id).val(content).trigger('change');
    },
    decodeContent: function (content) {
        var result = content;

        if (this.config.add_widgets) {
            result = this.decodeWidgets(result);
            result = this.decodeDirectives(result);
        } else if (this.config.add_directives) {
            result = this.decodeDirectives(result);
        }

        if(result!=''){
            result = result.replace(/&nbsp;/g, ' ');
        }

        return result;
    },
    encodeContent: function (content) {
        var result = content;

        if (this.config.add_widgets) {
            result = this.encodeWidgets(result);
            result = this.encodeDirectives(result);
        } else if (this.config.add_directives) {
            result = this.encodeDirectives(result);
        }

        return result;
    },
    beforeSetContent: function(o){
        o.content = this.encodeContent(o.content);
    },

    saveContent: function(o) {
        o.content = this.decodeContent(o.content);
    }
};
```

});

Comment: I have solved this issue but now I found another issue in this.   If I insert image in first textarea and try to update image again or try to insert image in another textarea, browser will be freeze

Comment: Could you make your example a little more minimal? It'll be easier to debug if you can get the smallest possible example that still breaks.